# Why is echo behaviors different?

Tags: php, testing, echo

Today,

while We were referencing a book, we found out that echo have a multiple parameters, but with few testing, Its giving us weird behavior.

Here is a test:

```
echo("one", "two");
```

And here is another:

```
echo "one", "two";
```

The first test case is giving error, but second isn't..Why?

Comment: *Why?* -> Read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php *Additionally, if you want to pass **more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.** *

Comment: echo is not a function; it is a language construct that can take one or more arguments..... but if you're getting an error, tell us what the error is!!! I'm guessing that you haven't read: `Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must __not__ be enclosed within parentheses.` (my emphasis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation gives you the answer:

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. **Additionally, if you want**
>   **to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be**
>   **enclosed within parentheses.**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

So, in short: because `echo` is not a function - skip the parentheses. You can use parentheses if you want to echo only one parameter, but it's custom not to.

```
<?php
    echo 'Hello'; //Acceptable
    echo('Hello'); //Acceptable
    echo 'Hello ', 'world'; //Acceptable
    echo ('Hello ', 'world'); //Not acceptable
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. So the point I was missing was the language construct. I will have more research on it..